# Simplify Python Turtle plotting of similar functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to simplify this function, in terms of less if statements and typing the same code over and over?

This function creates sine graphs based on the number the user requests. There is a lot of repeating code. I tried to use lists to store the objects, but get an error when trying to access them. How can I fix this?

```
 def createWaves(amp, count):
            even_num = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
            alpha = createTurtle("turtle", "darkcyan", 2)
            alpha.ht()
            beta = createTurtle("turtle", "purple", 2)
            beta.ht()
            gamma = createTurtle("turtle", "orange", 2)
            gamma.ht()
            delta = createTurtle("turtle", "magenta", 2)
            delta.ht()
            epsilon = createTurtle("turtle", "deepskyblue", 2)
            epsilon.ht()
            zeta = createTurtle("turtle", "green", 2)
            zeta.ht()
            omega = createTurtle("turtle", "black", 3)
            omega.ht()
            if count == 0:
                alpha.st()
                for x in range(361):
                    y_alpha = (amp/even_num[0]) *(math.sin(math.radians(x*even_num[0])))
                    alpha.goto(x, y_alpha)
            elif count == 1:
                alpha.st()
                beta.st()
                omega.st()
                for x in range(361):
                    y_alpha = (amp/even_num[0]) *(math.sin(math.radians(x*even_num[0])))
                    y_beta = (amp/even_num[1]) *(math.sin(math.radians(x*even_num[1])))
                    y_omega = y_alpha + y_beta
                    alpha.goto(x, y_alpha)
                    beta.goto(x, y_beta)
                    omega.goto(x, y_omega)
            elif count == 2:
                alpha.st()
                beta.st()
                gamma.st()
                omega.st()
                for x in range(361):
                    y_alpha = (amp/even_num[0]) *(math.sin(math.radians(x*even_num[0])))
                    y_beta = (amp/even_num[1]) *(math.sin(math.radians(x*even_num[1])))
                    y_gamma = (amp/even_num[2]) *(math.sin(math.radians(x*even_num[2])))
                    y_omega = y_alpha + y_beta + y_gamma
                    alpha.goto(x, y_alpha)
                    beta.goto(x, y_beta)
                    gamma.goto(x, y_gamma)
                    omega.goto(x, y_omega)
```

Comment: What is the error that you see when you try to access a list?

Comment: To reduce repetition, create functions that perform common pieces of code. What immediately sticks out is your calculation which could easily be refactored as something like `def calc(amp, x, n): return (amp/n) * (math.sin(math.radians(x*n)))`.

Comment: @Matt I'm trying to store turtle objects into a list, then iterating through them to create the graph. But when I try to use the .goto method, it says that the object doesn't have it.

Comment: In fact, it probably makes sense to write a function for creating all the turtles in one go, and another function per if statement, just to keep it clean. As you start breaking stuff down, you'll begin to see patterns that will make things more obvious. Storing the turtles in a list and retrieving the number you need makes sense.

Comment: @SCB Would I be able to use a function like that, to continue adding on? for example, if you look at the last elif count == 2, I want to add the different y values using different amplitudes and periods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reimplementation that avoids the duplication and works for counts from 1 up, to the limit of `EVEN_NUMBERS` and `COLORS`:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

EVEN_NUMBERS = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

COLORS = ["darkcyan", "purple", "orange", "magenta", "deepskyblue", "green", "black"]

def createWaves(amp, count):

    screen.tracer(False)

    for x in range(361):
        y_offsets = []

        for i in range(count):
            turtles[i].showturtle()

            y_offset = math.sin(math.radians(x * EVEN_NUMBERS[i])) * amp / EVEN_NUMBERS[i]

            turtles[i].goto(x, y_offset)

            y_offsets.append(y_offset)

        if count > 1:
                turtles[-1].showturtle()
                turtles[-1].goto(x, sum(y_offsets))

        screen.update()

    screen.tracer(True)

screen = Screen()

turtles = []

for color in COLORS:
    turtle = Turtle("turtle", visible=False)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.width(2)

    turtles.append(turtle)

turtles[-1].width(3)  # summation turtle

createWaves(100, 4)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: This would create the graph one by one. I want it to create the final turtle live, while the other turtles are drawing. Would that be possible?

Comment: @SnehPatel, this runs all the turtles at the same time -- it is no different than your original in that respect.  I do not understand what you're asking me.

Comment: Sorry you are correct. For turtles[-1], that refers to the last item in the list?